# Will the quality of my negative samples affect the output of my haar trainer? OpenCV

Tags: opencv, cascade, sample, object-detection

So first off, I'm trying to detect music symbols off a sheet of music. Let's say, in this case, we're looking for the gclef http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/GClef.svg in this sheet http://www.anzacday.org.au/miscellaneous/lastpost.gif .

For positive samples, I used one clef image and rotated it in the angles I needed to cover all the possible shapes that are the changes from book to book. 2000 samples, using 1500 in the haartrainer.

For negative samples, I downloaded 3019 random images and am using them, after of course checking none of them had a gclef symbol. The negative images are clouds, offices, houses, buildings, trees, laptops. Actually I found a link to it on stackoverflow, please don't make me go look for it... using 3018 negative sampels.

Do the negative samples matter? i.e. if my negative samples are clouds and houses, would I get sharper result that if it were, say, the sheet music without the clefs? i.e. do the negative samples affect the object detection? I already created two cascade files with 10-14 stages and I got very different results. But creating 3000 negative samples by cropping music sheets is a pain in the butt...

My object detector isn't intended to work in the wild, but only on a scanned sheet of music, so the only thing it'll ever encounter are musical symbols... If Haartraining isn't the way, please point it out! Complete n00b, just figuring out my way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not expecting houses, trees and cars, why use them for negative samples?
Better use image patches actually occuring in your images to be analysed.
For example a bass clef will be a lot closer to a g clef than to a tree patch. Actually, almost every symbol on your image will be closer to a g clef than to a real world image, because you real world isn't bitmap style.

Did you use different rotations of your clef in one training? Don't do it! Haar training isn't rotation invariant. If you expect your sheet to be rotated, you should better rotate the image and run the detection for every rotated image.

Or... you could detect your sheet's orientation by detecting the lines (e.g. with hough lines), rotate it only once to have an upright image and then run the detection.

you could start with just a few samples for testing (let's say 10 positives, 100 negatives). Training won't take that long. A g clef should be easy to train, as it is very characteristic. If you see it's going in the right direction, you can add samples to refine your detector's quality.

Good luck! :)

btw.: are you a trumpeter? ;)

Comment: For the rotation part, that's exactly what we're doing. We're also trying to delete the lines after saving the coordinates, and it should facilitate the haar training.
I'm trying to find some available negative samples without having to do my own... But yeah, when my cascade file wasn't working I thought to myself the only thing I did wrong was the negative samples. Should I just use other symbols or full sheets?

Aren't those numbers low for haar training? More precise negatives is better, but 10 positive samples versus 1500? I'll try it out.

Thanks :D

Nope, a pianist.

Comment: Do you know where I could download musical negatives from?

Comment: negatives should be image patches of all size. Not just single symbols. You could write a little tool that extracts some randomly cropped image patches from music sheets - ideally having the same width-height-ratio as your trained object. Then just manually sort out patches mainly containing a g clef. You can for example keep big patches covering a third of the image containing a small g clef. Just remove patches that represent a g clef.

Answer (score 3):

yes, negative does matter, and you should train your classifier in the best condition possible, i.e. with images you will give it during prediction, that is images of musical sheets. So take as negative samples images extracted from musical sheets without g-clef. You can still add your other kind of images to the negative set.

Comment: That's what I thought! Thanks a lot! Do you know where I could download musical negatives from?

Answer (score 1):

heres a set of negative images:
http://tutorial-haartraining.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/data/negatives/

Comment: link not working :( do you have that collection of negatives somewhere else?